# Dsolve unreadable output

Tags: differential-equations

```
 DSolve[{(1+x+7x^2 - 3x^3 + 2x^4) y'[x] + (4x^2 - 2x + (1 - x)y[x] + 6) xy[x] == 0, 
                     y'[0] == 0},  y[x], x]
 C[1]=1
 Plot[y[x], {x, 0, 8}]
```

output very hard to read/understand can't put C[1]=1 won't plot

Comment: note `xy[x] ` is not same as `x y[x] ` but after correcting, result is given in terms of unresolved integral. But the main problem I see is that your IC is wrong. You should not give `y'[0]==0` as IC for first order ode.  Change it to `y[0]==0` and now you get very simple solution. But for general `y[0]==a` it is still in terms of integral not resolved. If Mathematica can't integrate, then you are left with implicit solution. Nothing to be done about this.

Comment: Thanks Nasser for correcting my syntax, and explaining very well what is going on.

Comment: fyi, I also tried it now in Maple, and it can't solve the integrals either. (i.e. with no IC at all). Screen shot. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLuWh.png)  so try `NDSolve` if you want numerical solution.

Comment: With syntax corrected in v7 it didn't respond in 20 min. Thanks Nasser  for trying Maple. Will study

Comment: That Maple screenshot helped me alot to understand the form of the ideal solution. v7 doesn't come back with anything at all.

Comment: Version 7!  wow, that is 2008 release. This is almost 15 years ago.  DSolve have improved alot since then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150611/discussion-between-simon-and-nasser).

Comment: Ok have new equation. Known answer. Can't get dSolve to work at all. My eyes need large font now, not resetting every cell.
Eqn is Batchelor Fluid Dynamics 5,12.4                                                        
              DSolve[y'''[x] + 2 y''[x]*y[x] + 2 y'[x]^2 == 0, y[x], x]

Comment: Nasser, can you please help me again. Like does your version solve this please